# как сопоставить атрибуты метода

Tags: java

Есть задача, я её приложил к вопросу, суть в том что есть заказы

```
 public void send(long orderId, boolean isBuy, int price, int size);
```

и требуется как то их сопоставлять друг другом, если цена заказа продажи и заказа покупки совпадают то заказ нужно убрать, не знаю как это реализовать

https://www.bookmap.com/shared/ExchangeTaskC.pdf

Comment: Задача простая. Не совсем понятно в чем возникла сложность. Приложите, пожалуйста, код который вы уже написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю задача тестовая (то есть надо показать свои скиллы), следовательно надо сделать "умно":

1) Завести класс/бин типа

```
class Order implements Comparable {
    long orderId;
    boolean isBuy;
    int price;
    int size;

    public int compare(Order order) {
         //blah-blah
    }
}
```

2) Далее написать к нему `compare()`, в котором если собственно говоря если 
один из них покупка, другой продажа и суммы одинаковы то возвращается `0`

3) Далее пробегаетесь по всем заказам сравниваете их друг с другом, те которые `compare()==0` *убиваете*

Уверен, это то вам по силам?